# Resolve another domain from current AD domain

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, internal-dns

We have 2 AD domain setup in our office. First is the primary domain for our office and exchange. The 2nd one is for development use to simulate production environment of our clients. Both domain are hosted on Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise. We, the development team has no access to the office domain other than login and email purpose. DNS is running on PDC of both domain. Both domain does not use public domain name.

Now, our machines are joined to the development domain and we use outlook to access our office's exchange. We've added DNS entries for both the domain. From time to time we are having problem resolving our office domain (i.e. during outlook login), which we need to edit our NIC's DNS to have only DNS server from our office and then flush DNS. After that switch back once it's able to resolve.

Is there a permanent solution for this scenario like specifying that the office domain be resolve with another DNS server when requested from the development domain?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Development DNS Server, add a conditional forwarder to your office DNS server for the Office domain.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794735(v=ws.10).aspx

> To assign a conditional forwarder for a domain name  1. Open DNS
>   Manager. To open DNS Manager, click Start, point to Administrative
>   Tools, and then click DNS.
>
> 2. In the console tree, double-click the applicable DNS server. Expand DNS, and then double-click Applicable DNS server.
> 3. In the console tree, click Conditional Forwarders, and then on the Action menu, click New conditional forwarder.
> 4. In DNS domain, type the fully qualified domain name (FQDN) of the domain for which you want to forward queries.
> 5. Click the IP addresses of the master servers list, type the IP address of the server to which you want to forward queries for the
>      specified DNS domain, and then press ENTER.